# get touch shape in Developer Option

Tags: android, touch

I want to implement function that shows touch data in Developer options.

More specifically, I want to get  shape of  screen and fingers meet. Maybe shape looks like ellipse.

[image: like this]

Is there any way to get source code of Developer options? or how can I implement these function?

Answer (score 1):

Android is open source. You can find the Settings app source code at:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/

Bear in mind that the Settings app uses *many* things that are not available to Android SDK developers.

Comment: thanks! but i can't find codes about developer mode...
SDK dose not support functions about touch area? i wanna get raw touch data...

Comment: @KelvinJ: If you scan through a copy of [the manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-cts-8.1_r7/AndroidManifest.xml) and search for "develop", you will eventually come across the `<activity>` element for `Settings$DevelopmentSettingsActivity`. I would start looking there and in its associated `com.android.settings.development.DevelopmentSettings` fragment.

Comment: i think there are no codes that function implemented. AOSP only has codes to turn on pointer_location option..